# Unable to run "HelloWorld" Azure sample in Development Fabric

Tags: visual-studio-2008, azure

I am trying to run the sample "HelloWorld" Azure application in the Development Fabric on my Windows 7 development machine. It compiles successfully, I can see it start up as the "Windows Azure Simulation Environment" appears in the status bar and when I bring up the DF UI I can see that a HelloWorld_WebRole is running but I get the following errror message in my browser:

> **Server Error in Application "ROLE SITE"**
>
> Internet Information Services 7.5
>
> **Error Summary**
>   HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
>   The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
>
> **Detailed Error Information**
>   Module: StaticFileModule
>   Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
>   Handler: StaticFile
>   Error: Code 0x80070032
>   Requested URL: http://127.0.0.1:5100/Default.aspx
>   Physical Path: C:\Projects\Azure-samples-cs\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.csx\roles\HelloWorld_WebRole\approot\Default.aspx
>   Logon Method: Anonymous
>   Logon User: Anonymous

The error message goes on to say that the most likely cause is that:

> The request matched a wildcard mime
>   map. The request is mapped to the
>   static file handler. If there were
>   different pre-conditions, the request
>   will map to a different handler.

Comment: Have you successfully passed "Task 1 –Run the dependency checker"?  Very important to run all of these before you try the lab/demo.

Comment: What happens if you change your url to 127.0.0.1:81/Default.aspx?

Port 5100 is higher that usual, it either sounds like the internal port of the simulation environments load balancer or the port on the development web server.

You might also set the web project as the start up project and see if it starts ok first.

Where does that detailed error you provided show up?  In the Development Fabric, IIS logs, windows events logs or Internet Explorer?

Comment: Marco - I have stepped through that task and it found no problem with my setup.

Jason - The error appears in Internet Explorer and if I go to http://127.0.0.1:81/Default.aspx I get the same error. I have set the web project as a the start up project and it starts ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I reproduced your exact error ... by disabling Asp.net on my machine.

Make sure you have Asp.Net enabled:
1. Start button 
2. Control Panel 
3. Turn Windows features on or off
4. Under Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Services/Application Development Features
5. Check ASP.Net
6. Click OK

Try Hello World again, it should work.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with IIS.  Do you have any other websites on your machine to check that IIS is working correctly?  If not you can do the following pretty quickly to test the config and permissions: 1. Open VS.Net 2. Create New Web application 3. In solution explorer, right click on project heading choose properties 4.  On the Web tab, choose the "Use Local IIS Web Server" option 5.  Click the "Create Virtual Directory" button 6. Save and hit F5

If that loads in the browser without error with a url of http://localhost/<projectname>/ then your IIS config and perms seems ok

Comment: This initially wasn't working for me, I was getting an error about permissions which I didn't copy down unfortunately. I then stumbled over this command to re-register ASP.NET: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i".

I ran the command and rebooted and this seems to have cleared the problem.

Thanks for your help, Jason.